# Encrypting a string using private key in php

Tags: java, php, encryption, php-openssl

I need to integrate with some service provider API, where each request needs to be signed with private key of our certificate and service provider will decrypt it using our public key and similarly for response service provider will encrypt it using their private key and we will decrypt it using their public key (Means we will share our Public Key between each other)

**Service Provider did not have sample code in php**

Instructions which they provided are:

- Get contents in Bytes to Sign (Using UTF-8 Encoding)
- Get the X509 Certificate (Private Key Certificate)
- Compute the Message Digest
- Sign the Message and generate attached Signature
  (use Detached/attached property of Signing Library)
- Encode your Signed Message into Base64 Encoding
- Send the Encoded Message on HTTP

Sample Code in Java provided by service provider:

```
string data = "SAMPLE REQUEST XML";
priv = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(name, passw);
CMSSignedDataGenerator sgen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();         
sgen.addSigner(priv, (X509Certificate)cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);                        
sgen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certs);                     
byte[] utf8 = data.getBytes("UTF8");        
// The 2nd parameter need to be true (dettached form) we need to attach original message to signed message
CMSSignedData csd = sgen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(utf8), true, "BC");
byte[] signedData = csd.getEncoded();
char[] signedDataB64 = Base64Coder.encode(signedData);
String str = new String(signedDataB64);
```

I have written following code in php:

```
$utf8_data = utf8_encode($xmlString);
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $utf8_data);
$bytesStr = implode("", $byte_array);
$data = file_get_contents('/path/to/abc.pfx');
$certPassword = 'certpassword';
openssl_pkcs12_read($data, $certs, $certPassword);
$private_key = $certs['pkey'];

$binary_signature = "";
openssl_sign($bytesStr, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

Now my question is my above code correct ? Also how openssl_sign give me signature + sample request data,

As i am not able to generate same encoded string which service provider has provided into their sample,

Comment: "is my above code correct"  Well, does it produce the desired results?

Comment: Are you trying to sign XML documents with a digital signature ([XMLDSIG](https://github.com/odan/xmldsig))?

Comment: @Daniel,  Yes, Patrick, :-) what i mean is did a wrote code correctly or not,

Comment: the javacode uses base64 encoding at the end where are you using that?

Comment: It's little bit more than sign and encode data. The Java code is creating a complete [pkcs#7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652) format of signature (it's a format to encapsulate signed hash, algorithm, certificate, etc..) you may want to use [openssl_pkcs7_sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php)